# is it possible to use two mqtt listening ports with single broker

Tags: mqtt, tcplistener, emq

we are using emqx (3.0). my emqx is running in 1883 port and it's getting data from devices with authentication(device authentication and topic authorization) in same port. I want to enable one more port for device un-authentication. That's why I enabled one more port for the same emqx. now emqx is running in two ports with same process id. I checked with netstat command it's showing same process id for both ports(1883 & xxxx). but through paho I am unanle to connect to emqx from xxxx port. it's showing connection lost error.

1883 port is working fine.

in dashboard also xxxx port is enabled.

but I'm unable to connect through paho.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple listeners with different configurations are supported by setting another `zone` in the emqx.conf. The default zones are `external` and `internal`:

```
listener.tcp.external = 0.0.0.0:1883
listener.tcp.external.acceptors = 8
listener.tcp.external.zone = external
...

listener.tcp.internal = 127.0.0.1:11883
listener.tcp.internal.acceptors = 4
listener.tcp.internal.zone = internal
```

You can add your own ones or just change the internal one as follows, if you don't need the internal zone:

```
listener.tcp.internal = 127.0.0.1:xxxx
listener.tcp.internal.acceptors = 8
listener.tcp.internal.zone = external
...
```